# DynamoDB StringSet is automatically unmarshalled when reading data with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I use StringSet elements in some of my DynamoDB tables on AWS.
I use AWS Lambda for my APIS. Until a month ago when I read an element with a StringSet in it via Query/Scan or Get I had the string set as an object of the following form:

```
{
  "wrapperName": "Set",
  "values": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ],
  "type": "string"
}
```

So my webapps are configured to get a result in this format.
However without any reason I'm aware of DynamoDB is now returning all StringSets as a simple string array, like the following:

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

This cause my web apps to crash. I can figure out some solutions to avoid this of course, but what I want is to understand why this suddently happened and how to go back to the previous format. My guess is that it is a configuration issue.

What could have cause dynamoDB to change the result format of a query ?

Here are some details about my configuration:

- This happen in both eu-west-1 and eu-central-1 regions.
- I use AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient class to query my data.
- DynamoDB API version is 2012-08-10
- Lambda Runtime is NodeJS 8.10 (I tried with Node 10.X, same result)

Here is an example of a query:

```
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: "eu-central-1",
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10",
  endpoint: "https://dynamodb.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
});

dynamo.scan({
  TableName: "foo_dev_1"
}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    response.statusCode = 500;
    response.body = JSON.stringify(err);
  } else {
    response.body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }
  callback(null, response);
});
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
I was embedding some dependencies in my Lambda function, which included AWS-SDK@2.504.0. In this case lambda uses the embedded SDK and not the version it originally include (2.437.0 for Node 8.10).
I switch my dependency back to 2.437.0 and successfuly got back to the previous output format of string set.
What I don't understand is why AWS changed the output like that.
I found no mentions on this in the changelog file of aws-sdk-js.

Comment: I see the change. They added a toJSON method three months ago that returns the list of values. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blame/master/lib/dynamodb/set.js

Comment: Well seen thanks. That's why it happen when calling JSON.stringify then. To go back to the old formatting we could override the toJSON method then.